# assign objects with their children, as seperate instances, to random points of a geometry, using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, instances

I want to put objects with their children, that are positioned in a collection, as instances to some random generated points.
I don't want to add all the objects of the collection, but a portion of them with their children. So I guess i need to check the separate children box, but that also affects the children of the objects!
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just put parents + children in one collection and use a node setup like this:

[image]

I just parented spheres together and the suzannes.

Comment: I don't want to add all the objects of the collection, but a portion of them with their children. So I guess i need to check the separate children box, but that also affects the children of the objects!

Comment: please add this comment to your question, because that wasn't clear to me by reading it. thx

Answer (score 0):

"Separate children" checkbox of Collection Info separates all children into individual objects, not just first level. I couldn't find a proper solution to it. My workaround was to join objects that should be selected together using *Ctrl+J* (**Object**->**Join**)

I think Geometry Nodes need a node to work with hierarchies OR a node that can pick assets.

Comment: i ended up separating the children in another category, made a geometry note to randomly generate them on their parents surface and then made an extra geometry node to randomly distribute the parents as i wanted.